# Need to send data through API upon record update

Tags: apex, update

I am trying to push data through the API to a semaphore box when the following occurs. I am a complete beginner and need help writing this apex class:

We have data submitted through a form to start a new trial with us. When the opporunity is created or later if it is updated, we need to send this data.

The field we want this call to be on is on the opportunity. Upon creation of the opportunity, if this field is not null, or whenever this field is changed:
Trial_End_Date__c

When this field is updated, we want to send the following information on the opportunity:
- Stage
- Primary Contact Role First Name, Last Name
- Primary Contact Role Email
- Trial_End_Date__c

Can anyone help me writing this?

Comment: Just by looking at your use case, it looks like you can achieve this using click only instead of code by using a workflow/time-dependent workflow. Have you evaluated that route?

Comment: I have not. So I could trigger something in a workflow to send info when the opportunity is changed?

Comment: Yes. You can use workflow to make an update on your records or you can invoke an outbound message (which seems like to be your use case) to pass values to an external service.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing that out now. Seems like it could be the simple solution I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While no one can really help you with writing exact code for your requirements, but just by looking at your use case, I can say that you can do this using Workflows. It's not that you cannot use Apex here but using Workflows seem to be a very obvious implementation approach.

Here are few pointers which can help you to get started:

- [Workflow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wf.htm&type=0)
- [Add Automated Actions to Your Workflow Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_workflow_rules_configure_actions.htm&type=0)
- [Time-Based Workflow FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)
- [Understanding Outbound Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm)

And if at all you want to use the Apex route to invoke a service callout, you can take a look here:

- [Invoking Callouts Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm)

Comment: You’re welcome and glad that it worked out for you.